# AsyncExecutor doesn’t seem asynchronous

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

*This question has been edited to provide as much information about the problem as possible, as someone suggested I should do. Now that there’s bounty on it—that only seems like the right thing to do. Good luck, people!*

*Don’t forget you can always ask additional questions if you feel there’s something I didn’t include!*

### Introduction

I’m working on a system for procedurally generating terrain as a character walks around using various different noises—mostly [perlin-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) and [simplex-noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_noise). The world itself has three dimensions, althought it’s viewed as [top-down in two dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Top-down_video_games) inside the game.

For those of you used to procedurally generating terrain, you’ll be aware of the fact that it’s necessary to use multithreading in order for it not to cause lag spikes within the renderer thread. That’s exactly what I’ve been trying to do, with a little help from [*LibGDX*](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)’s [`AsyncExecutor`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncExecutor.html), as well as the same library’s [`AsyncTask`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncTask.html), which is a task running on the thread offered by the `AsyncExecutor`.

### Problem

My problem is that the `AsyncExecutor` doesn’t seem asynchronous at all. It causes lag spikes within my renderer thread, which in theory could be from it using a resource that also is used by the renderer thread. The thing is, however, that the renderer thread generates in new “chunks”—I call them regions—that the `AsyncExecutor` then work on. The renderer thread isn’t allowed to render that resource until it has been fully generated by the `AsyncExecutor`.

#### `RegionHandler`

I have a class called `RegionHandler` which places new regions in the direction the player is moving and removes regions from the opposite directions—in order for the program not having to be aware of more than 13 x 9 regions at one time.

Here’s a brief piece of code explaining how it works—**the comments** are there to **simplify discussing different pieces of the code**:

```
// These ‘if’s are triggered when the player moves
// to a certain position
if(addLeft)
{
    // Adds new regions to the left and removes to the right
    // ...

    // Submit ‘RegionLoader’ task to ‘asyncExecutor’
    // with regions that needs be generated as well as ‘toSends’ which is
    // also part of that generation
    asyncExecutor.submit(new RegionLoader(toGenRegions, toSends));      
}
else if(addRight)
{
    // Adds new regions to the right and removes to the left
    // ...

    // Same as previous ‘submit’ to the ‘asyncExecutor’
    asyncExecutor.submit(new RegionLoader(toGenRegions, toSends));
}

if(addBottom)
{
    // Adds new regions to the bottom and removes to the top
    // ...

    // Same as previous ‘submit’ to the ‘asyncExecutor’
    asyncExecutor.submit(new RegionLoader(toSend, toSends));
}
else if(addTop)
{
    // Adds new regions to the top and removes from the bottom
    // ...

    // Same as previous ‘submit’ to the ‘asyncExecutor’
    asyncExecutor.submit(new RegionLoader(toSend, toSends));
}
```

The `asyncExecutor` is in fact and `AsyncExecutor` and the `RegionLoader` implements the `AsyncTask` interface. I’ve tested to see how long this piece of code takes to run through—this piece of code never takes over a single millisecond to run through.

The `Region`s are handled inside a list:

```
List<List<Region>> regions;
```

#### `RegionLoader`

This class is a task with the capability of being run by an `AsyncExecutor`.

```
private class RegionLoader implements AsyncTask<Object>
{
    private List<Region> regions;
    private List<ToSendInner> toSends;

    public RegionLoader(
            List<Region> regions, 
            List<ToSendInner> toSends)
    {
        this.regions = regions;
        this.toSends = toSends;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception
    {
        // Generates the ‘Region’s it has been given inside the constructor
        // ...

        return null;
    }
}
```

Once `call()` has finished it’ll set a `boolean` to `true` that allows for the rendering of that specific `Region`.

#### Furthermore

Although the `AsyncExecutor` is meant to be asynchronous, it causes lag spikes every once in a while inside the renderer thread. As mentioned earlier, this could be caused by the `AsyncExecutor` using the same resources as the renderer thread, but the renderer thread merely renders the `Region`s when it’s allowed to—for that reason I can’t see why that’d be what’s causing the lag spikes.

### What I’ve tried so far

I’ve tried using regular Java threads, but [I read somewhere](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading) that these might not work due to *LibGDX* supporting Android development and Android doesn’t have the same capabilities when it comes to multithreading—but I could truly be wrong!

#### Furthermore

Perhaps someone has experienced a similar problem over their game development careers? If so, maybe someone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can lower its priority, or reduce the number of Threads (maxConccurent) to less than your number of cores.

Comment: Oh, yes—I forgot to mention that—I’m already using `1` as for `maxConcurrent`.

Comment: Do you call `get` on the result right away? Or is it just a `Void` task?

Comment: @JornVernee I made a slight edit that should answer your question. Should it not, however—do feel free to expand on what it is you’re asking. I’m fairly new to the whole `AsyncExecutor` thing.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, `submit` returns an `AsyncResult` do you use that at all? I would also ask what exactly `RegoinLoader` does, like, does it use a synchronized resource that the render thread also uses? The 2 threads might be fighting over a resource.

Comment: @JornVernee No—as a matter of fact I don’t. I did a quick lookup on it and noticed it’s used for “allows to poll for the result of the asynch workload”—may this be a cause of the lag spikes? Is there something that needs be done after that of an `AsyncTask` has finished?

Comment: @JornVernee The submitted `RegionLoader`’s `toAdd` is used by both threads—this will be rendered at a later stage. But until the `RegionLoader` is done with it, the renderer thread isn’t allowed to render—this due to a `canRender` `boolean` located inside the `toAdd`.

Comment: That's probably causing the lag, there is no benefit to going parallel if one thread has to wait for the other. You could try to, instead of doing the whole batch at once, do 1 step and then release the lock so the render thread can keep rendering, things just won't be added in all at the same time.

Comment: @JornVernee What do you mean? The renderer thread shouldn't have to wait for the `AsyncTask`s, because that will render nonetheless—this due to that “lock”, which renders a certain `Region` only when its not locked, if  it's locked it doesn't even look into a `render()` method located inside it.

Comment: Oh I see, I thought it would wait until `canRender` was true to then call `render`. Any ways, you should add a little more information, at this point we can only speculate. It doesn't look like you're using `AsyncExecutor` wrong.

Comment: @JornVernee Additional details have been added and started a bounty.

Comment: Is this `List<List<Region>>` perhaps a synchronized collection? Are you passing the inner lists directly to the loader or creating a new list inside the ifs? And where are these `toSends` coming from? And something else, are you doing any I/O on the render thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a look into the effects of your garbage collection, as you seem to be passing new Region objects to the tasks.  Try reusing/repopulating existing Regions instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember any problems about Android and Threads and searched but didn't find anything. You should test it.

I will assume that generating regions is not anything related to openGL. So you don't have to run it on main thread.

Try this: **Thread + Gdx.app.postRunnable()**

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    Variables...
    public Runnable set(Variables... ) {
        // set variables
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do stuff

        Gdx.app.postRunnable(() -> {
            // commit that stuff.

        });
    }
}.set(regions,whateverelse)).start();
```

If you look at the source code of AsyncExecutor you will see that it exactly does the same. But only it doesn't let a second runnable run at the same time.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/9b8f20b2d0e96e53f0f2b98dc8f6131c810aae71/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/async/AsyncExecutor.java

**Note:** The implementation of the AsyncExecutor is changed to instantly execution in the gwt backend. Because of the limitations I'd guess. You probably shouldn't target gwt.

Try it, and let me know. If main thread still hangs, it is because what you are doing in the **//commit that stuff** part. Post more of your code, there is not enough to understand the source of the problem.

**EDIT :** Also use Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() to see if there is really a hang. It might be caused by something else, so eliminate other possibilities and find out if the real reason is this task.